# Simple IRB Question regarding Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

I have a class called Deal.

Deal has vote_scores.

I would like to see how many vote_scores are in Deal that are greater than 2.

My guess :

for vote_scores > 2 in Deal
count
end

Doesn't really work :D

Edit:

I tried everyone's ideas. But note that :

> > Deal.vote_scores

Doesn't work because vote_scores is not an attribute of Deal, but rather an attribute of one of its Deals. So if I did this :

> > Deal.find(1).vote_scores

would return a #.

vote_scores is instantiated within the haml here:

```
.deal_summary{:id => "deal_#{deal_view.id}"}
.score
  = deal_view.vote_scores
```

in the model here:

```
def vote_scores
  self.votes.inject(0){|sum, vote| sum + vote.value}
end
```

Comment: deal has_many vote_scores??? And what params vote_score has got? What should we compare with 2? vote_score.score > 2???

Comment: Describe VoteScore model. What attributes does it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to know how many, the more efficient code will be:

```
Deal.count(:conditions => ["vote_scores > ?", 2])
```

This will be faster since the counting is done in sql rather than in ruby.

**EDIT**

Okay, we can try this:

```
Deal.find(:all).select {|e| e.vote_scores > 2}.count
```

This will return total number of deal object that has vote_scores > 2

Hopefully that is what you want to do.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer, is that what you want to do?

Comment: Sooo strange! This works on my local but on my live server, it returns that there is no method for 'count'..How strange is that? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes I got it! Beacuse its an array, you can't use count. But .size works!

Comment: You can always change count to size if you want to

Comment: this method is way less efficient than my answer below.  it returns all records from the database before filtering by vote_scores.

Answer (score 0):

Deal.find(:all, :conditions => ["vote_scores > ?", 2]).length

Answer (score 0):

```
deal = Deal.first #or whatever... Deal.find(10)
deal.votes.count :conditions => ['value > ?', 2]
```

for all Votes

```
Vote.count(:conditions => ['value > ?', 2'])
```

Comment: of course undefined! I've updated comment. You should firstly define exact Deal for what you want to know votes count

Comment: What if I want to find out the count of all of the deals' vote_scores above 2?

Comment: Vote.count(:conditions => ['value > ?', 2'])